# I'm trying to create custom column in google sheets with query funcion

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create custom column in google sheets with query function.

for instance (in order to be simple) - I have this data.

[image]

and the result should look like this, if Revenue is more than 500 000 - Good and if not Bad:

[image]

is this possible to do this with query? I would appreciate you help.

```
=QUERY(A1:B4,"select *")
```

here is the link

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/129fUbXN_vaYVUocz5L3uN2M2ZUTVuPMy5-whfWx9qtY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
={A2:B,arrayformula(if(B2:B="",,if(B2:B>500000,"good","bad")))}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I want to know if there is way to do same with query formula.

Comment: no, in any way it requires vlookup or nested if to retrieve good/bad answers

Comment: ok. I understand. thanks.